# Is it possible to use wordpress on some pages of my site only?

Tags: static-website

I am making a website, and part of it will have dynamic content, as well as easier for me to manage as there will be less code involved.

for example, The website.com/home page, /users page and /payments etc pages are all static and managed by an admin panel that someone has built for me, with its own Database.

however I want to have a website.com/news  /blog   /contact pages, in which are built on wordpress, as it is much easier for me to make, since I have more experience with it, thus I can make contact forms to my email, dynamic blog posts, etc without needing to code it since im not that experienced with that.

I have done some research and have seen it is possible to host subdomains on different hosts, eg use Host 1 for the website.com, then redirect the DNS for sub.website.com to another host that uses wordpress, however is there a way so that I can make it so website.com/slug pages use wordpress and others do not? If so is it possible to do this on the same host, or will I need a different host and change the DNS for those /slugs?

**UPDATE:**

Here is what I plan to do, I am going to host the admin panel on subdomain.example.com, and the payment process is going to be embed code on the main page, with cross domain linking (he told me how to do that). then on the actual website and all pages on example.com It will have CMS (im thinking Drupal or processwire),

using that CMS I am going to implement User accounts, Referral system, Rewards system, as I will be able to do to it myself rather then get the coder to remake the payment code.

Thus there will be two databases, one for the payment system, and one for  the CMS with user accounts/referral/rewards. The payment database will have read only access to the  CMS database, in order to assign USER IDs to each payment transaction, and the CMS database will likewise have read only access to the payment database, to calculate total transaction volume, and thus referral earnings/reward points.

Is this system safe and will it now slow down the website? given they will be reading each other all the time? or would it be a better idea to put them all in one SQL database, and just have different Tables, is there any security issues / other issues with this?

Comment: Yes.  What you could do, for those static pages, is just make custom templates in your theme with the static HTML page code in theme.  Then, in WP, make pages like 'home' and assign the static 'home' template to it.  Does that make sense/

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, and there are likely many ways of doing it.

It would be easier to invert the logic, and say "if a page exists, display it - otherwise feed it to wordpress and let wordpress display/handle it".  This is actually the default on most Wordpress sites, as its more-or-less required for "pretty URL's", which are important for SEO.

If the server is using Apache and you can modify the .htaccess file it is possible to reverse the logic and program what is pulled from Wordpress and what isn't by modifying the rewrite rules.

**Expanded Info**

I've made some reasonable [- ie very common but not always correct] assumptions below.

(At least on Apache), Wordpress normally has a .htaccess file or equivalent which includes the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

This Basically instructs the web server to check if the requested URL maps to a file or a directory - and if it does not, feed the request through Wordpress.

As long as the resource you are trying to reach is either the name of a directory (which would be the case if your URL did not have a filename on the end - in which case the web server will look for a file like index.php or index.html or a few other defaults in that directory - or a filename) and exists, that resource will be fed directly by the filesystem.

You could thus have https://www.example.com load up your wordpress site, and https://www.example.com/payment - and (for example) create an (public_html)/payment/index.php - with the code to process payments, and the webserver would be smart enough to know to not process that url through Wordpress.

Comment: right, and for pages that are ran from PHP (payment page eg) just do not create a page for them on Wordpress, instead just set the links to them on wordpress pages to that URL?

They would have to be in different directories correct?

so the PHP sites would be php/payment  php/history etc
and the wordpress sites would be /wordpress/news  /wordpress/contact

or would it be possible to have them all in the same directory?

Comment: See my updated answer.  You could put wordpress and the payment gateway at the same level, but that would make things messier then they need to be (from a "what happens when someone goes to the root directory perspective) - but yes, that will work.

Comment: Hi, could  you please check the update in the original question and tell me if you think this plan is good? thanks

Comment: Had a look at update.  It does not sound immediately bad, but as you have custom code and have not mentioned the MPM module Apache is using (or if you have user seperation or chroot we cant begin to say how secure it is).  Wordpress should be considered insecure because - if you take into account plugins - ot has an attrotious security history - with a new serious vulnerability in a common plugin found every other month - so isolatomg wordpress from everything else at a server level is important, non-generic and non-trivial.

Comment: As to whether it will slow down the website depends on the webserver specs.  On a low-end VPS, yes.  A decent new server would likely be an order of magnitude overkill.  You probably meed a minimum of 8 gigs of RAM to be safe, although you could tine the system to use less - especially if you have a way of mitigating bot hits (eg using cloudflare)

Comment: am going to use Drupal CMS instead of WP, Main website with Drupal located public_html/Website  and admin panel public_html/AdminPanel.  admin panel will be on subdomain with cross domain configured (or maybe just a sub directory). admin panel for payments Hashes settings, and cannot be edited unless the creator admin is logged in, other admin accounts that can log into admin panel do not have access to settings (which payment destination, amounts are all in). The Database for both payments/admin panel and the Drupal for accounts/rewards etc will be on the same database. Is this safe? thanks

Comment: No one can answer that without intimate knowledge of all the code.  Its not wildly unsafe, but its not particularly secure. If you think of good security as built up in layers - its not secure design as if one part is compromised (ie allows execution of php)  the rest of the site is easily compromised.  There are lots of mitigatioms thay can be put in place, but you have not mentioned any - which is fair enough, because its a whole differrnt skillset)...

Comment: You are better off having seperate databases then 1 database. Its not clear if you are going to be running Wordpress *at all*. If so - as described - unless extreme care is taken your entire system is not particularly secure.  Using something like Wordfence and  geavily limiting wp plugns would help - but ideally (if you want to keep it simple) have the Drupal CMS on a seperate server/virtual server and use a reverse proxy to merge the sites.